# maximum answers on survey + unique rate

Tags: 2007, survey-list, unique

In SharePoint 2007 I need to create a survey with 10 question and to give each question a rate from 1 to 5.

Is possible using no code to create this survey and allow users to respond only to maximum 5 question for example ? Second question , how can I force that the rate given for each of this 5 responses to be unique ?

Thank you

Comment: Personnaly, it's not possible to do this with just OOTB functionalities. You need specific development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it without any use of code.
I think the simplest solution to this is to use jQuery/JavaScript to make sure each answer is unique (on top of my head: each time a user select an answer i would save it in an array and then compare the next answer to the array - if there is a similar answer in the array then it’s not unique and i would show an alert or something).
The same goes for the other requirement of maximum 5 questions: if the array of answers length is 5 then i don’t let the user answer anymore, whenever he select an answer i pop up an alert.

Comment: yes, using code the ideea is to add a webpart on the NewForm.aspx page of the survey. This webpart will come also with some js that can solve the requirements. But code not allowed...